# derivation of standard error - Why can we assume all variances can be the same?

Tags: variance, standard-error

I'm learning how to derive standard error of the mean mathematically.

I understand that standard error is the square root of the variance of the mean:

$SE =\sqrt {Var((x_1+x_2+...+x_n)/n}$

And understand

$$SE = 1/n \sqrt {(Var((x_1+x_2+...+x_n))}$$
$$SE = 1/n \sqrt {(Var(x_1)+Var(x_2)+...+Var(x_n)}$$

But I don't know why all variances of x are the same. i.e. $ Var(x_1) = Var(x_2) = σ $

Texts say "each individual observation has the same variance as the other individuals" or "the $x_i$ are identically distributed, which means they have the same variance $σ^2$".

This is the step I feel doubtful. 1) Why can we assume all variances are the same? 2) Also, what do we mean by "variance of $x_1$, $x_2$", when the x's are only point estimates rather than a collection of raw data points (such as variance of x, variance of 30 heights)?

Thank you for answering.

Comment: The "variance" refers to the iid random variables $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ from where you perform sampling, not to an individual realization (observed values) which are written in lowercase $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$.

Comment: Does "The random variables" indicate "average"?
So, in my question, do you mean I should change the small x's to large X in all the three lines starting from SE?

Comment: "The random variables" indicate an underlying distribution. For example when you sample the height of random people, the underlying distribution is normal with mean of about 70 inches and standard deviation of 4 inches. It doesn't make sense to talk about the variance of the height of a individual person (it is zero), but if you repeat your random experiment and draw a histogram you should see the underlying distribution.

Comment: ... and yes, you should put uppercase $X$ in your formulas.

Comment: Thank you for answering the second question.
Still, I don't understand why the variances are assumed the same......

Comment: Think for example of n coin tosses. You would expect that the probability of getting a head and probability of getting a tail to be the same for each individual coin toss. And the variance should be the same.

Comment: Ah, the mean and variance actually refer to the population.....